# Updating table with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a data table that I am trying to append rows to when there is new data to display. I'm relatively inexperienced so I took the easy way out on this and wanted to write a script that checked the database for updates every second instead of listening for server-sent events. I tried to write an Ajax query that would get all the objects in the data table, and if their 6th value is false (which means they have not been loaded), then it would add a row to my data table with that information. My tables are in a Django webapp, and here's the code I have tried to implement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var table = $('#example').DataTable();
          setInterval(function(){
            newrequests = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/main/newrequests/",

                // I tried this and it didn't work

                // success: function(data) {
                //     for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                //       // check if the request has been loaded
                //       if(data[i][5] == 0)
                //         // if not, load and set to loaded
                //         table.row.add(data[i]).draw;
                //         data[i][5] == 1;
                //     }
                // }
            });

            for(i=0; i<newrequests.length; i++){
              if (newrequests[i][5] == 0){
                table.row.add(newrequests[i]).draw();
                newrequests[i][5] = 1;
              }
            }

          }, 1000)
      });
</script>
```

I have a view set up for /main/newrequests which simply all the objects in the database:

```
def newrequests(request):
    return HttpResponse(Request.objects.all())
```

When I update the database, the data table does not refresh. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I feel like it might be how I am trying to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatable already has an option for that:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": '/main/newrequests'
});

setInterval(function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: I didn't know dataTables had that function - thanks. When I try implementing it, it gives an error HTTP 500. I looked at a few more tutorials online and my view for that page that ajax is pointed to is: 
    
    def newrequests(request):
    requests = Request.objects.all()
    data = json.dumps(requests)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')

Do you know why this returns an error instead of reloading the table?